Abortion and States' Rights in the US
If a fetus is a person, it's not a citizen until after it's born, per the Constitution. That would make birth a process of naturalization (converting a stateless non-citizen fetus into a citizen).
But states don't have any authority to regulate naturalization or immigration. How can there be states' rights with regards to abortion if it would be regulating naturalization?


That would make birth a process of naturalization (converting a stateless non-citizen fetus into a citizen)

No it wouldn't.  The immigration and nationality act defines naturalization as "the conferring of nationality of a state upon a person after birth, by any means whatsoever."  Conferring nationality at birth is not naturalization.
On top of this, the nationality consequences of birth do not mean that any legislation concerning birth is nationality legislation.  Nationality is a side effect of birth.  Similarly, federal income tax liability is a consequence of employment, but nobody argues that this prevents states from regulating their labor markets.
